# Swap two lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 2 lists, which are of equal size, in python like:

```
list_of_lists = [list1, list2]
```

In a for loop after doing some processing on both `list1` and `list2`, I have to swap them so that `list1` becomes `list2` and `list2` becomes a list initialized to all zeros. So at the end of the iteration the list_of_lists has to look like:

```
list_of_lists = [list1 which has contents of list2, list2 which has all zeros]
```

In C, one could just copy the pointers of `list2` and `list1` and then point `list2` to a list initialized to all zeros. How do I do this in python ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you are mainly working with `list1` and `list2` inside the loop. So you could just reassign their values:

```
list1 = list2
list2 = [0]*len(list2)
```

Python also allows you to shorten this to a one-liner:

```
list1, list2 = list2, [0]*len(list2)
```

but in this case I find the two-line version more readable. Or, if you really want `list_of_lists`, then:

```
list_of_lists = [list2, [0]*len(list2)]
```

or if you want both:

```
list1, list2 = list_of_lists = [list2, [0]*len(list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this...

```
list_of_lists = [list_of_lists[1], []]

for i in range(count):
    list_of_lists[1].append(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_lists=[ list_of_lists[1], [0,]*len(list_of_lists[1]) ]
```

The cost of the swap is the same as the pointer swap you mentioned